# Class Component to Functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

How do I convert this class component to a functional component? 
What I am trying to achieve is to subscribe and unsubscribe from firebase using useEffect()

```js
class PostsProvider extends Component {
  state = { posts: [] }

  unsubscribeFromFirestore = null;

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.unsubscribeFromFirestore = firestore
      .collection('posts')
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const posts = snapshot.docs.map(collectIdAndDocs);
        this.setState({ posts });
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.unsubscribeFromFirestore();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'd convert your component. You'd useState() to create your posts state and then a useEffect is pretty straightforward to move. The main thing you'd want to make sure of is that your dependency array is correct for it so it doesn't subscribe and unsubscribe too often (or not often enough).

```
function PostsProvider(){
    const [posts,setPosts] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribeFromFirestore = firestore
        .collection('posts')
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const posts = snapshot.docs.map(collectIdAndDocs);
        setPosts(posts);
        });
        return () => {
            unsubscribeFromFirestore();
        }
    }, [])
}
```